# p4python run describe is not returning list

Tags: python, perforce, p4python

```
p4.connect()                   # Connect to the Perforce Server
info = p4.run("info")          # Run "p4 info" (returns a dict)
changes_results = p4.run('changes','-s','submitted', '//components/rel/...@2017/11/01,@2017/12/31')


changes_lists = []


for change_result in changes_results:
    change_list = change_result['change']
    changes_lists.append(change_list)



print('Total Change list found ', len(changes_lists))
for idx_main, change_id in enumerate(changes_lists):
    print('\n\n\n', change_id, idx_main)
    result = p4.run('describe', change_id)
    print(result)
    depotfiles = result[0]["depotFile"]
    filesrevision = result[0]["rev"]
```

For some change list, this is working perfectly fine p4.run is returning list and I am able to extract change list file and their revision number.

But sometimes p4.run is not returning proper list and instead returning string and I am unable to extract changelist files and their revision number and giving below error

depotfiles = result[0]["depotFile"]
TypeError: string indices must be integers

Is there issue with P4 or my code.

Comment: What string? What does `print(result)` print when `result` is a string?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most straightforward way to get the list of files in a changelist (or anywhere else) is the `p4 files` command.

I.e. replace:

```
result = p4.run('describe', change_id)
print(result)
depotfiles = result[0]["depotFile"]
filesrevision = result[0]["rev"]
```

with:

```
for result in p4.run('files', '@='+change_id):
    print(result)
    depotfiles = result["depotFile"]
    filesrevision = result["rev"]
```